# Can't find this I2C Bus Error

Tags: i2c

I have an example of I2C communication, but there is an error, and I can't figure it out.
The Start and Stop conditions are good, the address has 7 bits, data has 8 which is correct. I think the error is between ACK and D7, but not sure.
[image]

Comment: If it is it positive clock edge triggered it would produce an error according to your diagram.

Comment: Is the error in a real application or are you supposed to find the error in the bus sequence you posted (like for an assignment)?

Comment: this is an exercise, the error is intentionaly put. It is not a real application

Comment: For homework questions we expect you to demonstrate a substantial effort to find your own solution. What do you know about I2C and how the protocol is supposed to work?

Comment: You suspect the error to be between ACK and D7. But it looks fine to me (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsoQF.png, [UM10204](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf)). This "glitch" happens when the SDA line is handed back from the slave to the master.

Answer (score 2):

The master device should probably NACK after the data.  Assuming this is the last transaction.  No idea the context.

Edited: Corrected to say master instead of slave.  Thanks @Seir for the correction.